# Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 - Driver Not Found

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, drivers, usb-headset

I have the latest driver (Version 1.4) downloaded from Microsoft's website. The driver installs fine, but the headset still has a yellow icon in device manager. Just to confirm that the headset actually works, I tested it in a virtual machine (VMware) running Windows 7 Ultimate and it picked it up right away without me having to install the driver manually. I'm not sure why it isn't working on my desktop.

Just a little background, I have not used this headset for a few months (maybe years). I was using a regular 3.5 mm jack headset until it just broke today. This headset is a USB headset. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out that there are a few files that are necessary in order for USB composite devices to work properly (USB devices with audio and/or video). These files need to be located in **C:\Windows\inf**. The list of files are as follows:

- **usb.inf**
- **usb.pnf**
- usbport.inf
- usbport.pnf
- usbprint.inf
- usbprint.pnf
- usbstor.inf
- usbstor.pnf
- usbvideo.inf
- usbvideo.pnf

I was missing the first two that are in **bold**. I'm not sure how or why I was missing them, but I'm just glad it was a simple fix. To retrieve these files, I simply grabbed them from a fresh Windows 7 installation on a virtual machine. You can probably grab them from another computer you have in your home too.